# Win-Shift-Arrow keyboard shortcut stopped working on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> stopped working on Windows 10. It should move Windows to adjacent screens.

I looked at the `WM_HOTKEY` events with Spy++ as described in [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows). There weren't any!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I remembered having changed some multitasking setting in Control Panel a short while ago. Turns out that the <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>left/right arrow</kbd> hotkeys are only available if "Arrange windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or corners of the screen" is enabled under "Multitasking" in Control Panel.

PS. There still aren't any `WM_HOTKEY` events when I use the hotkey. Apparently it uses some other mechanism to capture the events.

Comment: n.b this is called "snap windows" in the multitasking part of the windows 10 style control panel.

Answer (score 0):

For others with this problem: Dell Displaymanager takes over and disables several of these win+shift/ctrl hotkeys. If you have that running and have this issue, try closing that software (context menu / right click from its tray icon, "exit").

That worked for me, the hotkeys immediately worked again.

(Note, similar reply here: https://superuser.com/a/788204/557294).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem for me: it happend just because i hade doubled the size of the windows task bar at the bottom of the screen.
Reboot and the same.
Just put the task bar the same size, and it's ok...

fun fact: i doubled the size of the bar, because the head of my cat sleeping in front of my screen was masking some icons...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).