# Win+Shift+Down stopped working for undoing vertical maximization

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10-v20h2

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> maximizes the active window vertically while maintaining its width.
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> used to do the reverse, that is, restore the previous vertical dimensions.

The latter stopped working in Windows 10 20H2 (maybe already in 2004). Instead, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> now always minimizes the window like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, as if ignoring the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier. I tested this on several independent installations and also in Safe Mode.

EDIT: I also checked with Spy++. The key messages go to the respective active window (as expected), except for `VK_DOWN` which doesn't appear. Instead a `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `SC_MINIMIZE` is received. There are no `WM_HOTKEY` messages.

Is there some way to restore the previous behavior?
Is there some other keyboard shortcut to undo the vertical maximization?

Comment: You have eliminated the possibility of third-party software being to blame?  I wasn't able to reproduce on either my 2004 or 20H4 VMs.  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1498855/win-shift-arrow-keyboard-shortcut-stopped-working-on-windows-10) might be helpful.  If that still does not help [this](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1) might help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: I reproduced the problem on three unrelated 20H2 installations (not VMs), and now also in Safe Mode. Therefore I think it's very unlikely to be caued by third-party software.

Comment: I also tried the different Multitasking settings, but the only effect I can achieve is to also disable Win+Shift+Up.

Comment: I provided a link that suggested 2 methods to diagnose the reason the shortcut wasn't working.  Have you tried either of those methods?

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I tried that, see my updated description.Windows Hotkey Explorer only works up to Windows 7, and HotKey Detective only reports WM_HOTKEY messages, which Spy++ shows aren't produced, i.e. no conflicting hotkey is registered.

Comment: Just to confirm, I checked yet another 20H2 machine (19042.746) and I can confirm that [WIN+DOWN and WIN+UP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec) work like always, but once WIN+SHIFT+DOWN is used the active window is lost.  Which is probably the reason it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on counting on Windows for consistency across upgrades, you may use
the free [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/)
to create your own hotkeys.

The following script implements your hotkeys:

```
sysget, SM_CYMAXIMIZED, 62                  ; Get maximised window size
sysget, SM_CYEDGE, 46                       ; Get 3D border size
return
; maximize vertically
#+Up::
WinGetClass, class, A
WinGetPos, X, Y, W, H, A
WinMove, ahk_class %class%, , (X), (0-(SM_CYEDGE*2)), (W), (SM_CYMAXIMIZED)
return
; un-maximize
#+Down::
WinMove, ahk_class %class%, , (X), (Y), (W), (H)
return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click it
to test.
You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the traybar and
choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

One slight problem with the above script is if you maximize one active window,
then activate another window and press the unmaximize hotkey, this will resize
the second window to the old height of the first window.
If this is a problem, the script can be improved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, AHK is on my to-do list, as Windows 10 gets increasingly annoying with their changes (as you pointed out). But I want to know if this is indeed a problem with 20H2, because it seems like a rather obvious regression if it is.

Comment: Not shocking at all - regressions crop up regularly on our site. But I don't have available an older version of Windows 10 to compare.