# Win-Key + Arrow does not snap windows on Win10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, aero-snap

I am having the issue that <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←/→</kbd> does not snap the windows to the side of my monitor, this is similar to

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3isu82/help_aero_snap_suddenly_not_working_with_winkey/
- http://www.justanswer.com/computer/681gq-windows-key-plus-right-left-does-not-work.html
- [Window key+arrows hotkeys not working](https://superuser.com/questions/249495/window-keyarrows-hotkeys-not-working)
- [Win-Key + Arrow keyboard shortcuts no longer working](https://superuser.com/questions/182829/win-key-arrow-keyboard-shortcuts-no-longer-working)

The Solutions on all these places explain how to (re)enable Aero Snap, but Aero Snap is working for me, I can snap the windows with the mouse (for example), just not with the keyboard. Other keyboard shortcuts (all) work fine, e.g. I can shift monitors using (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←/→</kbd>), so it is a very, very specific shortcut failure.

Of course, I have also tried disabling and re-enabling 'SNAP' in 
“SETTINGS  > SYSTEM > MULTITASKING, that does not fix the keys-specific issue. I have tried using the on-screen keyboard and the problem persists.

One possible red-herring is that I recently disabled 'narrator', (<kbd>Capslock</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>), as described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/blue-outline-on-everything-i-click-on/cca92fa8-3207-4572-900b-9b6fe5ea0f1c), that is the only system modification I can remember making in the last week.

The keys-shortcut problem appeared completely arbitrarily, without a computer restart or keyboard reinstall or other modifications.

Comment: haha, restarting the computer solved the problem - service desk 101.

Comment: You should consider adding your own answer to your question.

Comment: 90% of windows problems are solved by a restart or 2, I have had some systems that took 3 restarts before things started working normally.

Comment: I keep getting this. Very annoying none of the solutions apply / work for me. Very very annoying. All other combos I use work fine. Keys on their own work fine Just win + arrows problematic wonder if there is an easy way to setup alternative key combos?

Comment: ConEmu caused it for me, see this answer: http://superuser.com/a/1091991/132859

Comment: thanks @dvdgsng! restarting explorer was no help, but restarting conemu did the trick.

Comment: [Issue #1077 on ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1077) might be related?

Comment: based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones hold your `shift` key while drag a window

Comment: based on  also you can use `win`+`shift`+\` to costomized your zone on **each monitor**

Answer (score 30):

You have to enable **Snap** from Settings, System -> Multitasking.

[image]

Comment: Oh- damn it. This was the answer I was looking for but looks like I can not have "windows+arrow key" keyboard shortcut enabled, and have the snapping feature disabled. It is really annoying dragging windows across monitors and have my mouse stuck on the side of one of the screens.

Comment: I had this setting ON and it didn't work. After I set it to Off and then back to ON it started working.

Comment: Same for Windows 7: disabling snapping windows also disables those `Win+Arrow` shortcuts. Find "_Ease of Access Center > Make the mouse easier to use_".

Answer (score 23):

If you want to avoid a restart, you can restart the explorer.exe process.

## Step by step

1. Open Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)
2. Go to the Details tab
3. Kill the `explorer.exe` process.

[image: Kill explorer process]

4. In the Task Manager, click `File --> Run new task`

[image]

5. Type in `explorer`

[image]

Comment: cool, i can't try it obviously, but I guess this might troublehshoot other problems as well.

Comment: There are many annoying Windows UI problems that can be fixed by restarting explorer.exe .  It doesn't lose anything except currently open windows.  And perhaps if you're renaming, moving, or copying a file while you're doing it.

Answer (score 8):

I tried every one of the suggested fixes on this solution and on the other page links at the top.

None of them seemed to work. I rarely use the <kbd>Win</kbd> key outside of "Windows Snap" shortcut, so I tested a few other <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> hotkeys (e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) - didn't work either. So what I thought was a "<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd>" (aka Win Snap) issue - wasn't the actual problem...

Solution (Fixed Everything) :: **DISABLED "GAMER MODE" Toggle Key** on Mechanical Keyboard. (Logitech G910). I never use Gamer Mode Toggle and didn't even realize it was Enabled.

Hope that helps anyone out there w/ Gamer Mode Toggle Keys cause this has been bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the original question also lies in Ease of Access / Mouse settings -- see it at [this link (posted by zaraTzara)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-key-arrow-keys-not-working/41683031-032c-429d-b2b0-a6dc5a111ddc):

1. Go to:  Control Panel >> All Control Panel Items >> Ease of Access Center >> Make the mouse easier to use
2. Under ‘Make it easier to manage windows’:  Uncheck ‘Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen’.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me on Windows 10, stopped right after I had just been using it. Explorer has some bug evidently which stop listening for the shortcut key. The <kbd>Windows</kbd> key still works, but the key sequence <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd> is ignored by the OS.

Enabling or disabling **Snap** via <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> **Multitasking** had no effect - the feature was not the problem.

#### Command Prompt

```bsh
@powershell kill -name explorer
```