# Win+Right, Win+Left shortcuts not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, aero-snap

Somehow <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> shortcuts that are used to snap the window to the left or right of the screen don't work any more. They worked fine a few days a go and now the stopped working.

Other <kbd>Windows</kbd> key shortcuts work fine, the the arrow buttons work fine.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Did you install windows powertoys ?, because some people have faced this problem due to it.

Answer (score 12):

It's because the snap option has been disabled. Just open start menu, type *Snap* and select *Snap settings*. Alternatively open settings > system > multitasking

There you'll see the *Snap - Arrange windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or corners of the screen*. Just enable it and the shortcuts will work again

[image: snap]

See also

- [Win-Key + Arrow does not snap windows on Win10](https://superuser.com/q/1037929/241386)

Comment: I had the same issue. This fixed it for me. I had installed the Dell monitor management software for my computer and it had disabled snap. Thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue except that Snap and all successive checkboxes are toggled **on**. Any ideas?

Comment: @Chad try the solutions in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1037929/241386). If it doesn't help then you'll need to ask another question

Answer (score 2):

If you close a window that is currently snapped then re-open it, it generally breaks one of the snap directions. e.g. if I snap VSCode to the right side of my screen, close it, then re-open it, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> will work, but <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> will not.

Comment: I have been running into this as well, and I've found the behavior very confusing. Thank you for at least explaining how to consistently repeat the issue, and at least give me a way to "correct it". When this happens, I'm able to un-snap the window and close it. Then both Win+Right and Win+Left work again.

Answer (score 1):

Find Multitasking Settings and switch Snap on.

Comment: Please clarify and add a little more context to this answer to convey what you are suggesting exactly. You know, consider adding some reference to this answer supporting what you state.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as OP. Here are my snap settings: https://imgur.com/a/iSaPX

Comment: Update: for me the problem was solved after a reboot

Comment: We need to learn how we can prevent this reboot. What process is resposible and can be restarted to fix this. It appears to be explorer.exe.