# Windows 10 - Can't enable snap windows feature, and one option is missing

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, aero-snap, multitasking

I have windows 10 and at some point win key + left arrow/right arrow stopped working for me.
Another related issue I'm having is that when I try to move a non-maximized window it gets maximized.

From what I understand this is all related to the "Snap windows" feature in the Multitasking tab as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1214916/winright-winleft-shortcuts-not-working-in-windows-10).

The problem I have is that I can't seem to be able to enable this feature.
I can toggle the on/off button, but when I exit the settings or go to another tab and then to the multitasking tab again, I see the toggle has been automatically disabled.
Also, I do not seem to have the "Arrange windows automatically by dragging them to the sides or corners of the screen" option.

[image]

I have made sure there are no windows updates available.
I also tried restarting the computer.

What is the cause of these problems and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try setting Scaling (Settings, System, Display) to 100%, restart and see if the Snap to Feature returns. Also make sure Tablet setting is Off.

Comment: Which Windows 10 version? Check in *Control Panel > Ease of Access Centre > Make it easier to focus on tasks* if the option "Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen" is enabled (disable if it is).

Comment: @John - that did it!

Comment: Thank your. I posted a solution so you may wish to acknowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (from some prior experience):

Set Scaling (Settings, System, Display) to 100%, restart and see if the Snap to Feature returns.

Also make sure Tablet setting is Off.